# Incrementing a variable or assigning an iterator-element to it

Tags: python, iterator, variable-assignment

I want to increment a variable and - if a particular condition is fulfilled - I want to assign the next element of an iterator to it. In both cases the result should be appended to a list.

Problem is, that the function only recognizes the values already in the iterator.

The input-data is a nested list.

```
import datetime as dt

dates_prices = [[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54],
                [dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]]

def fillDates(dates_prices):
    filled = []
    iter_data = iter(dates_prices)
    item = iter_data.next()
    filled.append(item)
    while True:
        item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)
        try:
            if item in dates_prices:
                item = iter_data.next()
            filled.append(item)
        except StopIteration:
            return filled

a = fillDates(dates_prices)
print a
```

The function should check, which dates are missing in the original nested list. It should add all missing dates together with the last known price-point, so the output shoud be this:

```
a =
[[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54], 
[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 4, 0, 0), 48.54], 
[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 5, 0, 0), 48.54], 
[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]]
```

What did I miss?

EDIT:

I altered the function that it is working now by creating a seperate list of dates from the nested list "dates_prices" and applying the suggestion by Sevenforce.

However, I still don't know why my first solution didn't work. I guess something with the variable assignment was wrong. But I don't know what.

This is the new function:

```
import datetime as dt

dates_prices = [[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54], [dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]]

def fillDates(dates_prices):
    filled = []
    dates = [x[0] for x in dates_prices] #added this list
    iter_data = iter(dates_prices)
    item = iter_data.next()
    filled.append(item[:])

    while item[0] < dates[-1]:
        item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)
        if item[0] in dates: #using the new list here
            item = iter_data.next()
        filled.append(item[:]) #added colon here
    return filled


a = fillDates(dates_prices)
print a
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample input, with the expected output?

Comment: Input is a nested List. I added example-input and made my code executable. Sorry for not doing that in the first place.

Comment: And what is the expected output?

Comment: And I abandoned the "try-except" clause because it doesn't give me one anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am suspecting `dates_prices` is a nested list.

You possibly want to add a **copy** of `item` to `filter` and not the same object. To do this, change the line `filled.append(item)` to `filled.append(item[:])`. This will prevent `item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)` from changing already appended values in filled.

---

To answer your edit:

- Another `[:]` was missing: `iter_data = iter(dates_prices[:])` prevents changes in input `dates_prices` itself (by `item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)`, btw this is still happening in your updated code). This led to `if item in dates_prices` always evaluate to `True`.
- With above change `if item in dates_prices` will be always `False` since `[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 48.54] != datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]` and therefore leads in an endless loop.

Another working version (edited):

```
import datetime as dt
import copy

dates_prices = [[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54],
    [dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]]

def fillDates(dates_prices):
    filled = []
    iter_data = iter(copy.deepcopy(dates_prices))  #to copy the datetime objects
    item = iter_data.next()
    filled.append(item[:])
    dates_idx = 1
    while dates_idx < len(dates_prices):
        item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)
        if item[0] == dates_prices[dates_idx][0]:
            item = iter_data.next()
            dates_idx += 1
        filled.append(item[:])
    return filled

a = fillDates(dates_prices)
print a
```

But there is still room for improvement, like using a dictionary for `dates_prices`.

@jsbueno:
You are right. The thing to learn here is to use something like

```
new_item = [item[0] + dt.timedelta(1), item[1]]
```

I think.

Comment: Yes input is a nested list. But I applied your changes to my example and it still only returns the two values in the input data.

Comment: You found the problem, but did not fix it in the proper place - what breaks the program is  the assignement to the same data in memory -

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

It needs to be clear that a list is an **object** and is **mutable**.

So when you modify an element is for example item = [1, 2] with item[0] = 5 item will now be [5, 2].  If you put item in say... another list several times or for clarity a tuple (which are **immutable** objects) the item references do not change, but the contents of the items do.

Example of above:

```
In [162]: foo = [1, 2]

In [163]: bar = (foo, foo, foo)

In [164]: bar
Out[164]: ([1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2])

In [165]: foo[0] = 5

In [166]: bar
Out[166]: ([5, 2], [5, 2], [5, 2])
```

You may be confused but this really hits the point home.  The **tuple did not change** and **cannot change**.  The tuple simply contains the reference to an object, which we are not changing by changing the contents of item.  Example continued below illustrating these points.

```
In [167]: baz = [1, 2, 3]

In [168]: bar[0] = baz
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/litzomatic/Dev/sqlalchemypy/<ipython-input-168-a23696d7bc75> in <module>()
----> 1 bar[0] = baz

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

In [169]: foo.extend(baz)

In [170]: bar
Out[170]: ([5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3])

In [171]: baz[0] = 6

In [172]: bar
Out[172]: ([5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3])
```

Now, what should we do if we do not want this behavior?  You need to **instantiate several objects**, not just one.  In Python with lists there is a simple syntax for this.

```
In [174]: bar = (foo[:], foo[:], foo[:])

In [175]: bar
Out[175]: ([5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3])

In [176]: foo[0] = 10

In [177]: foo
Out[177]: [10, 2, 1, 2, 3]

In [178]: bar
Out[178]: ([5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3], [5, 2, 1, 2, 3])
```

You can confirm what is happening by using the `is` operator to compare object references.

```
In [179]: bar[0] is foo
Out[179]: False

In [180]: bar = (foo, foo, foo)

In [181]: bar[0] is foo
Out[181]: True

In [182]: foo[0] = 15

In [183]: bar[0] is foo
Out[183]: True

In [184]: bar
Out[184]: ([15, 2, 1, 2, 3], [15, 2, 1, 2, 3], [15, 2, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: But it should append "item" to "filled" independently of "item" being in "dates_prices". ´code´if item in dates_prices´code´ is only the condition for "item" to be updated by the next element of "iter_data". Doesn't it?!

Comment: Yes, you are correct, guess I read it wrong! :(  The source of your problem is very apparent with your input/output provided.  Others have mentioned the source of your problem, but I'll reiterate above because it's an important point.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are referencing (not copying) a list when you fetch an item from  your original `date_prices` list - and then you make changes to that list in the line

```
    item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)
```

I mean - your "item" here is being used several times in the list you are creating (and on your origial list) - it is the same data in the memory.

To fix that, make a copy of the item, before applying this assignment - for example, insert this line before the assigment:

```
    item = item[:]
    item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)
```

This will make your "item" become a copy of all the values of the previous item, and you then apply changes to this copy instead.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code, **item**  is a list:
then, doing `item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)` modifies the value of this list without changing its identity ( = location in the memory , given by `id()` )

This list **item** being an element of the list **dates_prices** , and its identity remaining the same, the list **dates_prices** continues to hold the same object at the same location in the memory, but the value of this object changes from  [dt.datetime(2008,6,3,0,0), 48.54] to  [dt.datetime(2008,6,4,0,0), 48.54] in the list **dates_prices**

Consequently the test `item in dates_prices` produces **True** and for this reason `item = iter_data.next()` is immediately executed => the object resulting from `item[0] += dt.timedelta(1)` isn't recorded into **filled**

My solution:

```
import datetime as dt

dates_prices = [[dt.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54],
                [dt.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]]

def fillDates(dates_prices, daylta = dt.timedelta(1)):
    # dates_prices must be ordered accorded to dates
    all_dates = [el[0] for el in dates_prices]
    ending_date = all_dates[-1]
    itnext = iter(dates_prices).next

    item = itnext()
    filled = [item]
    dateplus = item[0] + daylta

    while dateplus<=ending_date:
        if dateplus in all_dates:
            item = itnext()
        else:
            item = [dateplus,item[1]]
        filled.append(item)
        dateplus = item[0] + dt.timedelta(1)
    return filled

a = fillDates(dates_prices)

for x in a:
    print x
```

result

```
[datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 3, 0, 0), 48.54]
[datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 4, 0, 0), 48.54]
[datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 5, 0, 0), 48.54]
[datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 6, 0, 0), 47.99]
```

My code should be examined closer to see if particular cases wouldn't produce errors

.

### Edit

Better solution (shorter):

```
def fillDates(dates_prices, daylta = dt.timedelta(1)):
    d,p = dates_prices[0]
    filled = []
    for datime,price in dates_prices[1:]:
        while d!=datime:
            filled.append([d,p])
            d += daylta 
        p = price
    filled.append([datime,price])
    return filled
```

EDIT:

replacing `d,p = datime,price` with `p = price`